# Convert distinct records under one column into one singular row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have a table where all the records are identical, besides the values in one column.
Something like this:

| City | Warehouse | OrderID | CustomerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| San Diego | SD1 | 1234 | 5678 |
| San Diego | SD2 | 1234 | 5678 |
| San Diego | SD3 | 1234 | 5678 |

What SQL syntax/logic can I use in order to return one singular record, where the unique values from the Warehouse column are combined into one row?

Expected output:

| City | Warehouse | OrderID | CustomerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| San Diego | SD1, SD2, SD3 | 1234 | 5678 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string_agg` aggregate function. If the code that loads this value will decode back to an array of strings, then you can use the `jsonb_agg` aggregate function that will aggregate in a JSON array.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query. Group records by `City`, then use the `STRING_AGG` function.

```
SELECT City, STRING_AGG(Warehouse, ',') AS Warehouse, OrderID, CustomerID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY City,OrderID,CustomerID
```